# Can a Vue component/plugin have its own pinia state, so that multiple component instances don't share the same state

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have a "standalone" component which is set up as a Vue plugin (to be downloaded via npm and used in projects) and it uses pinia, but it looks like multiple instances of the component share the same pinia state. Is there a way to set up pinia such that each component instance has its own state?

The component is made up of multiple sub-(sub)-components and I'm using pinia to manage its overall state. Imagine something fairly complex like a `<fancy-calendar />` component but you could have multiple calendars on a page.

I have the standard pinia set up in an index.js:

```
import myPlugin from "./myPlugin.vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

const pinia = createPinia();

export function myFancyPlugin(app, options) {
    app.use(pinia);
    app.component("myPlugin", myPlugin);
}
```

Then myPlugin.vue has:

```
<script setup>
import { useMyStore } from '@/myPlugin/stores/myStore'
import { SubComponent1 } from '@/myPlugin/components/SubComponent1'
import { SubComponent2 } from '@/myPlugin/components/SubComponent2'
...

const store = useMyStore()
```

The sub-components also import the store. Also some of the sub-components also have their own sub-components which also use the store.

myStore.js is set up like this:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useMyStore = defineStore("myStore", {
    state: () => ({
        ...
    }),

    getters: {
        ...
    },

    actions: {
        ... 
    }
});
```

---

Edit: This is the solution I ended up using:

myStore.js:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia"

export const useMyStore = (id) =>
    defineStore(id, {
        state: () => ({
            ...
        }),

        getters: {},

        actions: {},
    })();
```

myPlugin.vue

```
...
<script setup>
import { provide } from "vue"
import { useMyStore } from '@/MyNewPlugin/stores/MyStore'
import { v4 } from "uuid"

const storeId = v4()
provide('storeId', storeId)
const store = useMyStore(storeId)
...
```

SubComponent1.vue

```
<script setup>
import { inject } from "vue"
import { useMyStore } from '@/MyNewPlugin/stores/MyStore'

const storeId = inject('storeId')
const store = useMyStore(storeId)
</script>
```

Comment: No, there is only one Pinia instance. Solve your issue by having each component instance create a separate pinia store instance and passing it (or its key) to the relevant dependencies. If you need help you should provide mode detail about your use-case.

Comment: The whole point of pinia is to be a shared state between components. A by-component state is simply the components data... Or you can create your own composable to act as a store.

Comment: @tao Yes, I'm just not sure how to create a separate pinia store instance for each component. What details should I provide? I have the above code in index.js, then myPlugin.vue is the main component which includes a dozen other sub-(sub)-components, most of which use the store. They all import the same ``myStore.js`` file and initialise it with ``const store = useMyStore()``

I could set up a simple demo if that would be helpful.

Comment: You're still not showing how you're creating the stores. My wild guess is you're using the same key, which is why you end up with a single store. You might want to provide a *runnable* simplified [mcve], using condesandbox or similar. It would also greatly help with testing potential solutions, for anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way of solving this is to create a stores map, using unique identifiers:

1. When you init a new instance of the root component of your plugin, you create a unique identifier for the current instance:

```js
import { v4 } from 'uuid'

const storeId = v4();
```

2. You pass this id to its descendants via props or provide/inject.
3. Whenever a descendent component calls the store, it calls it with the `storeId`:

```js
const store = useMyStore(storeId)
```

4. Finally, inside `myStore`:

```
const storesMap = {};

export const useMyStore = (id) => {
  if (!storesMap[id]) {
    storesMap[id] = defineStore(id, {
      state: () => ({ ... }),
      actions: {},
      getters: {}
    })
  }

  return storesMap[id]()
}
```

Haven't tested it, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

---

If you need hands-on help, you'll have to provide a *runnable* [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on which I could test implementing the above.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It actually worked. I also figured out there doesn't seem to be any need to use a storesMap, just pass the id and immediately run the function, this is what I ended up with: `export const useMyStore = (id) => defineStore(id, { state: () => ({ ... }) })()`